# Write WP Query that selects posts that are part of the same two categories

Tags: wp-query, query

How would I go about writing an intersect query (using WP Query) that returns a set of posts that are in both category A and category B?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Are you trying to do this for a custom query or to change the main loop? Are you using get_posts() or WP_Query()? What have you tried so far?

Comment: WP_Query -- I clarified my question to include that. In reading the documentation, I see where I can return a set of posts from multiple categories (all of category A and all of category B), but not where they overlap (ie. posts that are in BOTH category A AND category B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way using a default argument...

```
/*
* You need to get the IDs for the Categories you wish to include
*/
$args = array(
    'category__and' => array( 1, 3 )
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) 
{
    // Do something to display your posts
    ...
} else 
{
    // no posts
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a `tax_query` with the `AND` relation. [For example, this one cribbed from the Codex, with one change](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query):

```
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND', // here is the change
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'quotes' ),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'post-format-quote' ),
        ),
    ),
```